# How to redirect line-out to line-in on mac?

Tags: macos, audio, routing, recording

I want to route the output of my audio-interface ([Native Instruments Z1](http://www.native-instruments.com/en/products/traktor/traktor-for-ios/traktor-kontrol-z1/)) to a virtual input, so I can record / broadcast it using the broadcast tool [butt](http://butt.sourceforge.net/) (which only accepts inputs to stream from).

So I need a virtual device which allows me to route an output (channel 0/1 of Z1) to a virtual input.

I already looked at [Linein](https://www.rogueamoeba.com/freebies/) by Rogue Amoeba which redirects inputs to outputs, so not the direction, that I need. I also tried [soundflower](https://rogueamoeba.com/freebies/soundflower/), but none of them seems to be able to do the job. If this is possible using either of the tools, please let me know how.

Buying a second interface to physically route the output of Z1 to the input of the other interface would be the last option.

[image: Flow]

Comment: @DavidPostill: This doesn't look like it's about electronic devices at all, more about OS X audio software. (How much of the question did you read?)

Comment: @grawity All of it ;). The Native Instruments Z1 is a DJ Mixing Desk. The question is not very clear if it confused me. There is no mention of OSX in the question or in the tags :/ And there is another VTC ...

Comment: The question is all about software. Same problem exists without external hardware using just the build-in line-out of the internal soundcard.

Comment: @DavidPostill: It still seems to be used as a regular sound card in this case... I've seen some Windows drivers have a special input, e.g. SoundBlaster used to name it "What-U-Hear", that did exactly what the post asks for. On Linux, PulseAudio has automatic "monitor" streams. But **all the apps mentioned by OP are OS X apps**, and I've no clue about similar features there.

Comment: @grawity I've removed my VTC. Thanks for pointing it out ;)

Comment: In a [stack overflow thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18443621/mac-os-x-virtual-audio-driver) there are some more tools which go in a similar direction (but no solution for this problem).